# Tramp from Linux into a Windows machine and use the language development server from the Windows machine with eglot?

Tags: microsoft-windows, tramp, linux, eglot

I think everything is in the title.
I use Linux on a day to day basis.
I'm going to occasionally have to edit a C# project that is on a Windows machine. There is a C# development environment installed on the Windows machine. It would make my life easier if I could do everything from my Linux machine. However it would also make my life easier if I could use the C# development server that is installed on the Windows machine.
I would like to

- run emacs on Linux
- modify the files of the C# project (they are on the Windows machine)
- receive feedback from the C# language server that runs on the Windows machine

Is it possible to do that with eglot ?

I added this to my `/home/username/.emacs` file:

```el
(require 'tramp)
(add-to-list 'tramp-connection-properties
    (list (regexp-quote "/sshx:myusername@mywindowshost:")
        "remote-shell" "git-bash.exe"))
```

But the connection is closed immediately.

When trying instead:

```el
(require 'tramp)
(add-to-list 'tramp-connection-properties
    (list (regexp-quote "/sshx:myusername@mywindowshost:")
        "remote-shell" "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe"))
```

I get the complain that "C:\Program" is not a program. It's because of the space in "Program Files" but I don't see how to fix that, it seems that it's a bug in the "remote-shell" option of tramp, that didn't take into account possible cases with spaces in the remote shell's path.

I tried to symlink "git-bash.exe" in a directory that didn't contain spaces and use that path but then the connection closes immediately.